# Pytest hook executed twice with develop mode

Tags: python, pytest

When installing with `python setup.py install` my hooks get executed once, but when I used `python setup.py develop` they execute twice. Now I have CLI argument clashes in pytest. The structure is

```
setup.py
-- testing
-- library
```

I run setup from this directory and tried running pytest both from the same dir and from the testing dir.

Comment: Is there a question buried in there?

Comment: Sorry. Why is pytest executing the hooks twice? How can I make it stop? I'd like to continue development mode, reinstalling every time is tedious.